# xslt umbraco.library:FormatDateTime and the use of / (slash)

Tags: xslt, umbraco, formatdatetime

This may not be a real XSLT question but more of an Umbraco question.

This function as written will output another format as expexted:

```
<xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:FormatDateTime(data [@alias = 'kursusgangTilmeldingsfrist'], 'dd/MM/yyyy')"/>
```

When called with these three "second arguments" on the current date

```
'dd MM yyyy'
'dd-MM-yyyy'
'dd/MM/yyyy'
```

Then output will be:

```
10 02 2009
10-02-2009
10-02-2009 (and this should have been with "/" and not a "-")
```

Br. Anders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to escape using a backslash so function is called like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:FormatDateTime(data [@alias = 'kursusgangTilmeldingsfrist'], 'dd\/MM\/yyyy')"/>
```

And this will output correct date as:

```
10/02/2009
```